# Makefile with multiple outcomes

Tags: matlab, makefile, mex

This is my first attempt to write a makefile and therefore there is a lot of room for improvements.  I need to generate several mex functions for matlab on mac using the package sedumi and intel compiler studio.

Here is the makefile

```
# define matlab dir
MDIR = /Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app

# compiles mex files using g++
#CC = gcc

# compiler flags for g++
#CCFLAGS = -O3 -fpic

# to use the intel compiler instead, uncomment CC and CCFLAGS below:

# compiles mex file using the intel compiler
CC = icc

# compiler flags for intel compiler
CCFLAGS = -O3 -fPIC -D__amd64

# Figure out which platform we're on
UNAME = $(shell uname -s)

# Linux
ifeq ($(findstring Linux,${UNAME}), Linux)
    # define which files to be included
    CINCLUDE = -I$(MDIR)/extern/include -Ic++ -shared
    # define extension
    EXT = mexa64
endif

# Mac OS X
ifeq ($(findstring Darwin,${UNAME}), Darwin)
    # define which files to be included
    CINCLUDE = -L$(MDIR)/bin/maci64 -Ic++ -shared -lmx -lmex -lmat -lmwblas
    # define extension
    EXT = mexmaci64
    # CCFLAGS += -std=c++11 
endif

SRC:=$(wildcard *.c)

*.o: $(SRC)
    for i in $(SRC) ; do \
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -I$(MDIR)/extern/include -c -Ic++ $$i -o $${i%.c}.o; \
    done

OBJ0:=bwblkslv.o sdmauxFill.o sdmauxRdot.o
OBJ1:=choltmpsiz.o


all: 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) $(OBJ0) -o bwblkslv.$(EXT)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) $(OBJ1) -o choltmpsiz.$(EXT)

# clean up
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.$(EXT)
```

As it is, Makefile works just fine. make and then make all return the mex functions needed within matlab.

I have OBJ0 to OBJ37 and although adding the lines solves the problem I wonder if there is a simpler way to accomplish the same results.

Many thanks.

Ed

PS.  Thanks to the author of https://github.com/jtilly/mex for parts of the makefile.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You don't tell us what rule defines the value of your `OBJxx` variables. Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: @ Pacalet The rule that defines the value of each OBJxx has to be defined one by one and that is the reason you see OBJ0 and OBJ1 (and ... OBJ37). I can't see any automatic way to do it.

Comment: @e0k - I am not sure if the structure I choose for the makefile is optimized. What I need to do is: a) create obj files for all c sources in the dir and b) using each OBJxx rule, create the mex function choosing as the output name the first file in the OBJxx rule.   Can that be done differently from the solution shown above?

Comment: A similar problem - create obj files for all the c sources in the directory and for each individual file create a mex function.  One rule: obj and mex for each file.

Comment: In this particular I won't need each OBJxx rule and a simple line added to "*.o:" would do the job.

Comment: @EdMendes OK, I think I understood what you want. Initially I thought you wanted a way to automate the definition of your `OBJxx` variables from the list of existing C source files, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several aspects that you could improve:

1. Use make automatic variables (`$@`, `$<`, `$^`...)
2. Use a more make-oriented style for your C compilations, thanks to a [make pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

   ```
   SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
   OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))

   %.o: %.c
       $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -I$(MDIR)/extern/include -c -Ic++ $< -o $@
   ```

   This has several advantages over you shell loop. The most important one being that only one compilation is run when only one C file changes. With your solution all C files are recompiled when only one changes. Moreover, `*.o` is a wildcard that expands to existing object files. Not what you want, usually. Note that in your case you could also use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

   ```
   $(OBJ): %.o: %.c
       $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -I$(MDIR)/extern/include -c -Ic++ $< -o $@
   ```

   which looks almost the same but limits the rule to the specified list of targets `$(OBJ)`.
3. Use a macro and [`foreach-eval-call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) to instantiate the linker rules:

   ```
   .PHONY: all clean

   EXTS :=

   # $(1): variable name
   define MY_rule
   $(1)_EXT := $$(patsubst %.o,%.$$(EXT),$$(firstword $$($(1))))

   EXTS += $$($(1)_EXT)

   $$($(1)_EXT): $$($(1))
       $$(CC) $$(CCFLAGS) $$(CINCLUDE) $$^ -o $$@
   endef

   OBJVARS := OBJ0 OBJ1 ... OBJ37

   OBJ0 := bwblkslv.o sdmauxFill.o sdmauxRdot.o
   OBJ1 := choltmpsiz.o

   $(foreach v,$(OBJVARS),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(v))))

   all: $(EXTS)

   clean:
       rm -f $(OBJ) $(EXTS)
   ```

   Note the `$$` to escape the first expansion added by `eval`. For example, the first iteration of `foreach` instantiates the following rule:

   ```
   OBJ1_EXT := $(patsubst %.o,%.$(EXT),$(firstword $(OBJ1))

   EXTS += $(OBJ1_EXT)

   $(OBJ1_EXT): $(OBJ1)
       $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) $^ -o $@
   ```

   An easy way to design the macro consists in writing first what you want with, for instance, the `OBJ1` variable, replace each `$` by `$$` and finally replace `OBJ1` by `$(1)`.

Comment: @Pacalet. So so much better.  Thank you ever so much.  I do apologize for making the rulers not clear at first.

Comment: @Pacelet  I have moved OBJ0..OBJ37 and OBJVARS to the beginning of the script.  It has not changed the script outcome.  Is that a problem? Instead of typing each OBJxx in OBJVARS:=, is there an automatic way to do that?

Comment: @Pacelet I have modified the Makefile to deal with a simpler problem: for each c source a mex file is created. I have used the structure suggested by you but I could not figure out how to get rid of OBJxx's (there is a rule now - each c separately generates a mex function).  I have a solution but it does not use the nice "compile, generate obj and generate a mexmaci64 way" of your solution.   I know I have much to learn ahead of me.  Many thanks.

Comment: @EdMendes _It has not changed the script outcome. Is that a problem?_ No. The order is sometimes important but not in this case. _Instead of typing each OBJxx in OBJVARS:=, is there an automatic way to do that?_ Yes but you will need the [Gnu Make Standard Library (GMSL)](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) for integer arithmetic.

Comment: @EdMendes _for each c source a mex file is created_ what is the list of object files, in this case?

Comment: @Pacalet Many thanks.  The list of object files is the list of c source files. One c -> One obj -> One mex.   That goes for all files in the dir.

Comment: @EdMendes _One c -> One obj -> One mex_ Simple enough: look at the `%.o: %.c` pattern rule I suggested and write a `%.$(EXT): %.o` pattern rule. `$@` is the target (the mex) and `$<` is the first pre-requisite (the object file).

Comment: @Pacelet Many thanks.  I did that just that (my third comment) but first all obj files are generated and then the mex files one by one.  Not in the same way as in the approach shown in this thread (obj -> mex, obj -> mex, ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170197/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-ed-mendes).